# How to embed WidgetKit extension into Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, swiftui, widgetkit

[image: XCode is automatically managing signing][image: Here also on visual studio, signing identity is set as automatic]I have an application created in swift and a widget using WidgetKit extension in SwiftUI. Now I want to embed the widget extension into xamarin. I came across a microsoft document on how to embed WidgetKit support in Xamarin, the link is as: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/#embedded-widgetkit-support\](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/#embedded-widgetkit-support%5C) . Now when I am trying to embed it as given in the document, I am facing an error as, "ditto" exited with code 1. (MSB6006). I have gone through some references but still unable to resolve it.

P.S.  I have added the screenshots if it may help you.

Comment: Hi, if can't find the solution, you could submit it as an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues) in Github. Then follow it up there.

Comment: Hey @JuniorJiang-MSFT, thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it as well. But in my view it is probably  not an issue because embedding WidgetKit extension in Xamarin is possible. And MSB6006 issue usually arises when signing issues are there. I would be glad to know if anyone has come across this and have been able to resolve it. Just correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: Hi, I found that there is a [feedback](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8933) of this document. There is a same error code with yours: **"ditto" exited with code 1**, and finally the people has the same error solved this by referring this [PR](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/9048). You also could have a look at that to try.

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT. I will look at it.

Comment: Great, if solved that let me know that when you have time.

Comment: I have tried almost everything mentioned in the issues raised on github but I am facing problem in setting the signing identity. It is detected as blank though I have fiddled up with it. Do I need to create seperate provisioning profile on Visual Studio as well?

Comment: Hi, you mean the first step Provisioning is faild, and whether you could see the provisioning file in Xcode?

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate a bit more? Well on XCode the provisioning profile is automatically set. If this is what you are asking.

Comment: Okey, got it. When building the project in Visual Studio, you need to keep the provisioning profile the same with Xcode. But you said *" It is detected as blank though I have fiddled up with it."*, maybe you could share a scrrenshot of it. And I'm not sure whether you add the Apple account in Visual Studio. If no will not seeing the provisioning file.

Comment: I have put up the screenshots, hope it might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, however from the shared screenshot, it can not find the reason. Because a personal apple accout can not show in automaically signing recentlly. Therefore, I want to make sure that whether you build the project successfully in Xcode first? And you also could have a check with [the sample project](https://github.com/chamons/xamarin-ios-swift-extension) for xamarin ios.

Comment: Hey hi! Well yes the project is building fine on XCode. The application and the widgets both are running on XCode. It is the visual studio where I am facing problem. On visual studio, signing issue is coming.

Comment: Okey, I found that recently the personal team can not be seen in the Visual Studio. Not sure whether it will be related to this.

Comment: Sorry if you can please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, I mean that a free Apple account will not show the provisioning file in Visual Studio recently. However, it occurs on PC not Mac. And I have checked in my local site, it shows the personal team ID in **Signing Identity**. When running, it occurs the `ditto` error. I will continue to check the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the **BundleID** be the same between native app and xamarin ios app, then Xamarin iOS will select the correct provisioning file.

Native app:

[image]

Native extension:

[image]

Xamarin iOS:

[image]

**In addition**, you will see that extension and app also need to use the same App Groups.

Now the provisioning file will show:

[image]

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for a well briefed answer. Just to acknowledge you, the BundleID of both the native app and Xamarin iOS app is same in my case and also the app group for the native app and app extension is same.

Comment: @Krits Okey, if I set the same bundle ID and save modified in my local site, the provisioing file will show there automatically when clicking the pull down arrow.

Comment: Jiang Hey, I completely went through your detailed explanation and followed each step clearly. Now my ditto error is sorted and also I am able to embed the widget into xamarin app. Thank you so much for your wonderful explanation!

Comment: @Krits That's great! Glad be helpful.